# Error in dequeue method for a queue

Tags: java, queue

I'm not sure why I am getting an Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception, specifcally:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
```

The error lies in my dequeue method, and it is as follows:

```
public int dequeue ()
{
    if(isEmpty() == true)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        count--;
        front = (front + 1) % q.length;
        return q[front - 1];
    }
}
```

I've tried a few things, but I still can not come to a solution. All help is appreciated, and thanks in advance to all of those who reply.

EDIT (Solution):

```
public int dequeue ()
    {
        if(isEmpty() == true)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            count--;
            front = (front + 1) % q.length;
            return q[(front - 1 + q.length) % q.length];
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your method, I assume you are implementing a circular queue, if you look to this part of your `deque` method:

```
    front = (front + 1) % q.length;
    return q[front - 1];
```

You are moving the front of the queue and then returning the item that is before the new front, as the queue is circular, you could get `front` equal to `0` when `front` is equal to `q.length - 1`, hence your exception for trying to access the array with index = `-1`.

One way to fix it would be to apply a modular operation while returning the dequeued element like `return q[(front - 1 + q.length) % q.length];`, another way could be to store the element before moving the front, like this:

```
    int element = q[front];
    front = (front + 1) % q.length;
    return element;
```